# How to swap key value pair using aggregation pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks like so:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("65977bef1ccf990fe33ffc0d"), 
    "email" : "yww24@gmail.com", 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("65977bef1ccf990fe33ffc0f"), 
    "email" : "iqiyz@gmail.com", 
    "phone" : "8887774455"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("65977bef1ccf990fe33ffc10"), 
    "email" : "46d9s@gmail.com"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("65977bef1ccf990fe33ffc0e"), 
    "phone" : "6669997744"
}
```

I am trying to aggregate it so the result looks like this:

```
{
  'yww24@gmail.com': 1, // 1 can be any value (e.g. true, "yes", etc)
  'iqiyz@gmail.com': 1,
  '46d9s@gmail.com': 1,
  '8887774455': 1,
  '6669997744': 1
}
```

I can do that using the `lodash` library once the data set has been fetched from the db. I was just hoping to do this using mongodb (my assumption being that it will be less resource intensive, but I could be wrong).

So here is how I do it now:

```
Coll.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {}
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: false,
            email: true,
            phone: true
        }
    }
])
    .then(logs => {
        console.log(logs);
        const result = {emails: _.invertBy(logs, 'email'), phones: _.invertBy(logs, 'phone')}
        delete result.emails.undefined;
        delete result.phones.undefined;
        console.log({...result.emails, ...result.phones});

    })
```

Yes, the result is pretty much what I want, but, again, is there a way to do it on the db side:

```
{
  'yww24@gmail.com': [ '0' ],
  'iqiyz@gmail.com': [ '1' ],
  '46d9s@gmail.com': [ '2' ],
  '8887774455': [ '1' ],
  '6669997744': [ '3' ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my perspective, it is better not to customize the data for the projection on the database side when you can achieve it on the front-end/back-end side. Fetching data from the database should be a simple query or computation query. Imagine that when you have an extensive number of records in the database, this results in poor query performance and makes the database overloaded.

But if you are keen to do so, your query should be as follows:

1. `$group` - Group all documents into one.
2. `$set` - Set the `data` field.

   2.1. `$arrayToObject` - Convert an array of objects into a key-value pair.

   2.1.1. `$map` - Iterate each element in the array and transform into a new array.

   2.1.1.1. `$setUnion` - Combine arrays into an array. Alternative: `$concatArrays`.
3. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with the `data` object.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      phones: {
        $addToSet: "$email"
      },
      emails: {
        $addToSet: "$phone"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $setUnion: [
                "$emails",
                "$phones"
              ]
            },
            in: {
              k: "$$this",
              v: 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$data"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mZJs7oYOaWT)

Comment: Excellent stuff and excellent point on not messing with the projection too much. I will thoroughly test both methods and go with the quicker one.

Comment: Also, not sure what you try to achieve here, for me the value from the key-value pair looks unnecessary/meaningless if every key with value = 1. You may look for array which is easier for the data reading, iteration.

Comment: I need it in object form because I will be checking if email or phone exists in that collection and I don't want to be searching an array thousands of times. Instead I can just do something like `if(logs['email@gmail.com'])...` and know if the email exists. In array form, it would have to be `arr.find(el => el === 'email@gmail.com')`. And that will take a long time when the array contains, say, 500k records.